# Create small button

Tags: android, android-layout

My intent is to create many buttons in a line so I think each button must be small.

How to create small button like this?
[image: what I want]

I tried the below code but it is not similar.
[image: what I get]

This is my `style.xml`

```xml
<style name="RightLink2" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small">  
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:padding">2dip</item>  
  <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

this is my layout.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1">
    <Button android:id="@+id/myButton"        
    style="@style/RightLink2"
    android:text="Click here"/>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you intend to do many small buttons in a line, you are doing it wrong.

You are in effect, when programming for a phone, a UI designer. You have to remember your user will use his big fat greasy fingers while eating a hamburger and drinking soda, potentially, and still has to navigate your application easily.

There are guidelines about the minimal recommended size for a button, but you should use the following idea:

- if you have more than 5 buttons on your line, you're doing it wrong
- if you still want to put more than five buttons, you can either have one of the five buttons that opens a button pane/view, or slide the button line horizontally to reveal other buttons.

Both ways work, but I favor the second that i find both sexier and more usable. You will probably need a small indicator (as a triangle or equivalent) on the side to show there is more. Discoverability is important, and users are trained nowadays to try to slide stuff.

Comment: Its better to give answer first and then explain about problem or suggestions, as every application has different req .. here is the close answer I can get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258823/how-to-create-really-small-buttons-in-android-from-code

Comment: +Deepak Yadav actually, it is part of your job, in my opinion, to help the customer refine the application requirements. Therefore, no, "each application has their own requirements" is not an excuse for bad UI design, unless you're currently some code monkey who never gets to talk to any kind of "customer", and you should start looking for a better job. <intolerance mode off>

Comment: +Kheldar, <intolerance mode ON>one of many example with more than 5 buttons(10 buttons) in single row is an iPhone landscape mode calculator and I don't think thats bad ui design. So again YES it depends on SPECS or requirements. And being coding monkey is not bad as they get instructions from smart people like u :P So its your fault and you are not good at your job. Peace!!

Comment: +Deepak Yadav Heh, you might have a valid point here. I still think that actually, as a designer, you might be better off coming up with some awesome new paradigm for calculators (not that *I* have one) than small buttons, though, but it's nitpicking. Have a nice day man!

Answer (score 1):

This is not fair in user point up view.

Because, When user want to be press on one button then would be pressed two button at once time. You can do this, But it not a usable thing...!!!

Comment: Answer the question first.