# How to create really small buttons in android from code?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Android default Button class provides a really big button.

[image: button with caption "Save"]

There is a lot of wasted space around. Now I want to create really small buttons, that are only slightly bigger than the text/caption. How to do this from code?
So far I found the following method, but it is still providing too big buttons and wasting too much space:

A. Create an XML (smallbutton.xml) in the res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="color"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"

    android:textSize="8dp"
    android:maxHeight="2dp"
    android:maxWidth="2dp"

/>
```

B. From your code inflate this and add to the view:

```
Button pickBackColor = (Button) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.smalbutton,null);
```

...

```
LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

linLayout.addView(pickBackColor);
```

Now the problem is that the button is still too big, it uses too much space around (on the left, right, above, under) of the text.

[image]

Any hint how to decrease the size of the button further?

Answer (score 158):

Buttons have a minimal height and width (typically of 48dp respectively 64dp by default). So add

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
```

to get really small buttons:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! was going crazy finding out how to get rid of that unnecessary space above and below the text!

Comment: I love this, I almost gave up!

Comment: I've faced this problem after moving my app from API 7 to API 10 (alright, I want my app to run on some ancient crap); I originally had style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" on my buttons, but that style stopped working after the migration to a newer API. Thanks Maarten, now I don't need the style, as minHeight and minWidth do the work perfectly!

Comment: From a programmatic point of view, setting `setMinHeight` does nothing while `setMinimumHeight` does the trick. Why there are two methods is anyone's guess. Took me a while to get around that one. Same for width of course.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My button is large like the tableRow where appear it.

Answer (score 12):

For your information there is also the default style provided by Android that defines smaller buttons:

```
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
```

You can also if necessary modify this default style and define custom attributes in your file styles.xml. Here is an example with the modifications described in the question:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyleSmall" parent="android:Widget.Button.Small">
    <!-- Customizations  -->
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Then you just need to call it in the XML:

```
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/small_button"
   android:text="@string/example"
   android:contentDescription="@string/example_desc"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="@style/MyButtonStyleSmall" />
```

Comment: Can this be used programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

in .xml file...
you need to pass small value to layout_height and layout_width in xml file...... try this.

```
android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Change value as per your requirement...

Comment: Actually does anyone know where is it defined the "android:attr/buttonStyleSmall", in which XML file ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code:

```
pickBackColor.setWidth(VALUE);
pickBackColor.setHeight(VALUE);
```

Comment: This didn't help either. For some reason I am not able to decrease the size of the button.

Comment: Could you explain why would that help? IMHO this is not right, the way is through the minimal size of the buttons, which is hard-set and should be explicitly changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/food_item_minus_button"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_small_button_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_minus"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp" />
```